# How do I make C++/wxWidgets code accessible to a wxPython app?

Tags: c++, python, wxwidgets, swig

I have a code library which is written in C++ and makes extensive use of the wxWidgets library. I'm now trying to wrap my library (currently using SWIG) so that it's callable from wxPython, but I've hit a wall:

```
------ Build started: Project: MyLibLib, Configuration: Release_SWIG_OutputForBin Win32 ------
Performing Custom Build Step
In order to function correctly, please ensure the following environment variables are correctly set:
PYTHON_INCLUDE: C:\Python26\include
PYTHON_LIB: C:\Python26\libs\python26.lib
d:\MyProject\Software\MyLib\trunk\MyLib>C:\swigwin-2.0.0\swig.exe -python d:\MyProject\Software\MyLib\trunk\MyLibLib\MyLib.i 
d:\MyProject\Software\MyLib\trunk\MyLib>if errorlevel 1 goto VCReportError 
d:\MyProject\Software\MyLib\trunk\MyLib>goto VCEnd 
Compiling...
MyLib_wrap.c
C:\wxWidgets-2.8.10\include\wx/wxchar.h(886) : warning C4273: '_snprintf' : inconsistent dll linkage
        c:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\VC\include\stdio.h(358) : see previous definition of '_snprintf'
C:\wxWidgets-2.8.10\include\wx/buffer.h(127) : error C2061: syntax error : identifier 'wxCharBuffer'
C:\wxWidgets-2.8.10\include\wx/buffer.h(127) : error C2059: syntax error : ';'
C:\wxWidgets-2.8.10\include\wx/buffer.h(127) : error C2449: found '{' at file scope (missing function header?)
C:\wxWidgets-2.8.10\include\wx/buffer.h(127) : error C2059: syntax error : '}'
C:\wxWidgets-2.8.10\include\wx/buffer.h(127) : error C2059: syntax error : ')'
C:\wxWidgets-2.8.10\include\wx/buffer.h(129) : error C2061: syntax error : identifier 'wxWritableCharBuffer'
C:\wxWidgets-2.8.10\include\wx/buffer.h(129) : error C2059: syntax error : ';'
C:\wxWidgets-2.8.10\include\wx/buffer.h(129) : error C2059: syntax error : ':'
C:\wxWidgets-2.8.10\include\wx/buffer.h(134) : error C2061: syntax error : identifier 'wxWCharBuffer'
C:\wxWidgets-2.8.10\include\wx/buffer.h(134) : error C2059: syntax error : ';'
C:\wxWidgets-2.8.10\include\wx/buffer.h(134) : error C2449: found '{' at file scope (missing function header?)
C:\wxWidgets-2.8.10\include\wx/buffer.h(134) : error C2059: syntax error : '}'
C:\wxWidgets-2.8.10\include\wx/buffer.h(134) : fatal error C1004: unexpected end-of-file found
Build log was saved at "file://d:\MyProject\Software\MyLib\trunk\MyLib\Release_SWIG_OutputForBin\BuildLog.htm"
MyLibLib - 13 error(s), 1 warning(s)
========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
```

Is there a particular way I should be going about this? I spent some time googling for similar errors, but got none which suggests I'm probably barking up the wrong tree here...?

**[Edit]** Is [a dll and ctypes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/252417/how-can-i-use-a-dll-from-python) the answer?

**[Edit]** I tried including the main wx header in there, but it doesn't seem to fix the issue:

```
%{
#include <wx/wx.h>
%}
```

Am I going to have to go through and manually add each and every header from wxWidgets? Bear in mind there are a *massive* number of them!

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your `Mylib.i` is not emitting in its generated C file to `#include` the header(s) defining `wxCharBuffer` and so on (or maybe missing `#define`s that make those include actually perform the needed function definitions, but that's less likely).  Do you have the needed

```
%{
 #include "wxwhatever.h"
%}
```

and so on in your `.i` file?  Can you look at the generated `.c` and see what include directives are present or missing (or maybe in the wrong order)?

There's nothing especially tricky (that I know of) about the task you're attempting, and those error messages from the compiler just suggest to me "missing includes or the like"...