# Advanced uses of the msg * command in a batch file?

Tags: windows-7, popup, batch-file, cmd

**EDIT: I have started a bounty of 50 on this question to who ever gives the best answer!**

Hi i was wondering if there was a way for a batch file to make a pop up appear using the `msg * "hi"` command along with other selections besides the ones that are there by default (cancel and ok) by this, i mean add custom buttons to the pop up message such as a "next" button that would bring you to another pop up message  with dialog on it or something along those lines. In summary , is there a way to edit the results of the `msg * "text goes here"` command?

This is what comes up...

[image]

And this is kind of what i want:

[image]

However , i also would like to know if its possible to change the title of the pop up message and the size or position of it. I know that this is starting to sound like a gui based popup in a batch file but im just wondering if its possible by any means neccessary (Keep in mind that i only want to use batch/shell). Any information or ideas would really help! Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all I don't know some additional undocumented switches of `msg.exe` which you can use to create the message in the form which you want. Because you asked about *any information or ideas* I decide do to write my answer.

How you can see with respect of [Dependency Walker](http://www.dependencywalker.com/) the program `msg.exe` use internally functions `WinStationSendMessageW`, `WinStationEnumerateW`, `WinStationQueryInformationW`, `WinStationOpenServerW`, `WinStationFreeMemory` from the `winsta.dll` . The function [WinStationQueryInformationW](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa383827(VS.85).aspx) is documented, all other functions not. Nevertheless one can be relatively sure that the functions are identical to the documented function [RpcWinStationSendMessage](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc248836(PROT.10).aspx) and other RpcWinStationXXX functions documented in [Terminal Services Terminal Server Runtime Interface](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc248570(PROT.10).aspx). I personally see no need to use the undocumented functions because other documented functions [WTSSendMessage](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa383842(VS.85).aspx), [WTSEnumerateSessions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa383833(VS.85).aspx) (see [Remote Desktop Services API](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa383459(VS.85).aspx)) can do the same.

Both functions [WTSSendMessage](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa383842(VS.85).aspx) and [RpcWinStationSendMessage](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc248836(PROT.10).aspx) have parameters `pTitle`, `Style` (which can be [MB_YESNOCANCEL](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=93359) for example), and `pResponse` (which can be also interesting you you). So I suggest that you or one from your colleges just **write the small utility yourself which you need**. You can use documented [WTSSendMessage](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa383842(VS.85).aspx) and [WTSEnumerateSessions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa383833(VS.85).aspx) functions in the implementation.

If you'll ask a question of the [serverfault.com](http://serverfault.com) or [superuser.com](https://superuser.com/) probably somebody will recommend you an existing utility which you can use.

Comment: O im sorry, but i didnt understand a thing you just said, and i am well aware that there are more effective methods of doing this however i was just wondering if it was possible.... but i guess not..

Comment: @daniel11: I mean if one tool not do what you need you can write another one calling mostly only two functions `WTSSendMessage` and `WTSEnumerateSessions`. I suppose you can do this also from python (see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/252417/how-can-i-use-a-dll-from-python for example)

Answer (score 3):

Sorry but it's not possible to change the popup showed by the batch "msg" command.

What Oleg said is that if you want to create a custom popup, you can't do it with the windows "msg" command. There is no other way than creating your own "msg" command, which opens a custom popup (and there are many ways to do this, explained by Oleg).

Comment: oh i see, alright well thanks anyway! (i guess this was an easy 50 pts)

Answer (score 0):

the `msg * text` doesn't work in windows ten.I made a program to help though

```
@ECHO Off
echo -downloading paused-
echo MsgBox "are you sure you want to download 'msgBox extension' by Ronan? Oh wait ,sigh,I forgot to add the yes or no part...ok,hit ok for yes,or hit the X on the cmd terminal for no." > msg.vbs
msg.vbs
cls
del msg.vbs
echo alrighty then!
pause >nul
cls
@ECHO On
mkdir "msgBox extension"
echo start /min cache\messageB ^& exit > "msgBox extension\messageBox.bat"
echo blank..? > "msgBox extension\text.txt"
mkdir "msgBox extension\cache"
>"msgBox extension\cache\messageB.bat" (
echo set /p var=^< text.txt
echo echo MsgBox " %%var%% " ^> msgbox.vbs
echo msgbox.vbs
echo del msgbox.vbs
echo exit
)
pause
@Echo Off
cls
echo ok,good.you downloaded the software.just for good measure,do a scan of your computer,find viruses, THEN DELETE THE FOLDER ASAP. it means someone stole this program and added viruses to it.ooorrrrrrrr it's something else.
pause >nul
cls
echo now I will tell you how to use the software
echo in a batch file,or cmd prompt,: "msgBox extension\text.txt" will input text into the software. which will be used in : "msgBox extension\messageBox.bat" will display a text box of the imputed text.
echo good luck!
pause >nul
```

to use it though,in cmd or batch files,`echo text here > "msgBox extension\text.txt"` is the input,and `"msgBox extension\messageBox.bat"` will activate it via text box.