# how can i make more than 1 button appear in a popup box and can i make the buttons open programs

Tags: batch-file

I want to make a popup box apear when my computer starts up with 3 buttons in it, 1 to start word 1 to start firefox and 1 to start steam. Is there a way to do this in a batch file?

i know how to make a pop up box appear in batch:

> @echo off
>
> msg * this is where the message goes.

but this only makes a button saying ok.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4356053/advanced-uses-of-the-msg-command-in-a-batch-file. Do some research before you post.

Comment: I can do it from powershell.  But not from .cmd or .bat.  I have a form template in my powershell IDE with 3 buttons, if you ask I will post it.

Comment: knuckle-dragger please can you post that template and wich verssion of powershell should i use. i assumme the lastest (i think is 3)

Answer (score -1):

You must create a VBS Script to work with batch script, but i have no sure if is possible to make custom buttons, so you can make a little adjustment where the DialogBox will have three buttons (Yes[Word],No[FireFox],Cancel[Steam]):

```
@echo off
echo/WScript.echo MsgBox^(^"Start program^",vbYesNoCancel+vbInformation, ^"Start program^"^)>_temp.vbs
For /F "tokens=*" %%E in ('CScript //Nologo _temp.vbs') Do (Set "res=%%E")
::YES
if %res% == 6 (
::Here is the path to Microsoft Word
)
::NO
if %res% == 7 (
::Here is the path to FireFox
)
::CANCEL
if %res% == 2 (
::Here is the path to Steam
)
del _temp.vbs
```