# Python import dll

Tags: python, dll, ctypes

How would I import a winDLL into python and be able to use all of its functions? It only needs doubles and strings.

Comment: What do you have so far, and how doesn't it work?

Comment: Duplicate with this question?  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/252417/how-can-i-use-a-dll-from-python

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You've tagged the question [ctypes](http://www.python.net/crew/theller/ctypes/) and so it sounds like you already know the answer.

The [ctypes tutorial](http://web.archive.org/web/20110520120028/http://www.python.net/crew/theller/ctypes/tutorial.html) is excellent. Once you've read and understood that you'll be able to do it easily.

For example:

```
>>> from ctypes import *
>>> windll.kernel32.GetModuleHandleW(0)
486539264
```

And an example from my own code:

```
lib = ctypes.WinDLL('mylibrary.dll')
#lib = ctypes.WinDLL('full/path/to/mylibrary.dll')
func = lib['myFunc']#my func is double myFunc(double);
func.restype = ctypes.c_double
value = func(ctypes.c_double(42.0))
```

Comment: Well, I knew I needed ctypes but I didn't know how to use them. :)
Also, very good link! The python documentation seems to only be good for a reference, but not actual learning. Thanks a ton!

Comment: Wait! I think I overlooked your code. After looking at the tutorial, it seems to only demonstrate how to load windows DLLs. I need to load a custom DLL file. How would I do this?

Comment: @Patrick I've added another example. But it's all there in the tutorial. There's no theoretical difference between calling your own DLL and a Windows DLL.

Comment: I hate to bother you again... But could you check the code I put into the original question? Thanks!

Comment: @Patrick Please could you simply ask a new question. Include the code, both the ctypes code and the DLL function signature.

Comment: In you answer, what is `_lib`?

Comment: @Developer It's a typo, now fixed

Comment: @DavidHeffernan offtopic: Can ctype export c variables in dll to python?

Comment: Doesn't Python discourage the use of `import *`?

Comment: @steven It does. That was lifted from the ctypes tutorial. For the sake of a concise example I can see why they did that.

Answer (score 3):

I'm posting my experience. First of all despite all the hard work that take me to put all pieces together, importing a C# dll is easy. The way I did it is:

1) Install this nuget package (i'm not owner, is just very useful) in order to build a unmanaged dll: https://sites.google.com/site/robertgiesecke/Home/uploads/unmanagedexports

2) Your C# dll code is like this:

```
using System;
using RGiesecke.DllExport;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

public class MyClassName
{
   [DllExport("MyFunctionName",CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
   [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)]
   public static string MyFunctionName([MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)] string iString)
   {
       return "hello world i'm " + iString
   }
}
```

3) Your python code is like this:

```
import ctypes
#Here you load the dll into python 
MyDllObject = ctypes.cdll.LoadLibrary("C:\\My\\Path\\To\\MyDLL.dll")
#it's important to assing the function to an object
MyFunctionObject = MyDllObject.MyFunctionName
#define the types that your C# function return
MyFunctionObject.restype = ctypes.c_wchar_p
#define the types that your C# function will use as arguments
MyFunctionObject.argtypes = [ctypes.c_wchar_p]
#That's it now you can test it
print(MyFunctionObject("Python Message"))
```

Answer (score 3):

#### c-types NOTE!

Using `WinDLL` (and `wintypes`, `msvcrt`) is windows specific imports and does not always work, even on windows! The reason is that it depends on your python installation. Is it native Windows (or using Cygwin or WSL)?

For *ctypes*, the more portable and correct way is to use `cdll` like this:

```
import sys
import ctypes
from ctypes import cdll, c_ulong

kFile = 'C:\\Windows\\System32\\kernel32.dll'
mFile = 'C:\\Windows\\System32\\msvcrt.dll'

try: 
    k32    = cdll.LoadLibrary(kFile)
    msvcrt = cdll.LoadLibrary(mFile)
except OSError as e:
    print("ERROR: %s" % e)
    sys.exit(1)

# do something...
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [Cython](http://cython.org/), both to access the DLLs, and to generate Python bindings for them.

Answer (score 0):

Keep dlls file in System32 or  SysWOW64 folder in your 'C:\Windows' location. Use python `ctypes` or `cffi` library. If you use cffi library:

```
from cffi import FFI
ffi = FFI()
ffi.dlopen("kernel32")
ffi.dlopen("msvcrt")
ffi.dlopen("MyDLL")
ffiobj = ffi.dlopen('MyDLL2')
```

Or

```
import ctypes
kernel_32 = ctypes.WinDLL('kernel32')
```

It's working for me.

Comment: Any idea what `cffi` does differently from `ctypes`? (Why would you prefer one over the other?)