# Loading c dll in python

Tags: c, python-2.7

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Python import dll](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5253854/python-import-dll)

I am trying to load a c dll located at the same path where my .py script is, still I can not load the dll.

```
module = PyImport_ImportModule("<module-name.dll>");
```

Any suggestion.

Comment: It doesn't not use PyImport_ImportModule also I don't want to use Cython..

Comment: Sorry, I never did anything similar before. Have you tried supply only the module name (without .dll)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must call the line below to set your current directory in path, that is because by default, the current directory is not in the search path:

```
PySys_SetPath("."); 
mymod = PyImport_ImportModule("your_DLL_name or Py_module_name");
```

Once you have above code the C DLL or Python module will be loaded.

Comment: yeah.. the line did the trick.

Comment: Thanks, I am glad it worked for you.. I just saw your other question and I know the answer as well.

Comment: very good, I am waiting for your solution.