# Python NameError: name 'ctypes' is not defined

Tags: python, windows, dll, ctypes

I am trying to call a function from a custom .dll file. 
But when I try to load my library SDK.dll, i get the following error. I am following the indications found here: [Python import dll](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5253854/python-import-dll)

Does anyone know what the problem is? I only found references of this problem for MAC enviroments.

```
>>> from ctypes import *
>>> lib = ctypes.WinDLL('C:/Develop/test/SDK.dll')

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#19>", line 1, in <module>
    lib = ctypes.WinDLL('C:/Develop/test/SDK.dll')
NameError: name 'ctypes' is not defined
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

By doing `from ctypes import *` you are pulling everything from `ctypes` module to local namespace, so you should be calling `WinDLL` directly:

```
>>> from ctypes import *
>>> lib = WinDLL('C:/Develop/test/SDK.dll')
```

Another (and as mentioned by NPE usually better) way to do it is to import just `ctypes`:

```
>>> import ctypes
>>> lib = ctypes.WinDLL('C:/Develop/test/SDK.dll')
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, it worked. Now I get another error, `Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#21>", line 1, in <module>
    lib = ctypes.WinDLL('C:/Develop/test/SDKApplication/Debug/SDKCore.dll')
  File "C:\Python27\lib\ctypes\__init__.py", line 365, in __init__
    self._handle = _dlopen(self._name, mode)
WindowsError: [Error 193] %1 is not a valid Win32 application`, but I think this might be due to the fact that my python is 32bit, and the dll 64.

Answer (score 5):

Change

```
from ctypes import *
```

to

```
import ctypes
```

The former imports all names from `ctypes` into the current namespace. It is generally considered to be a bad practice and is best avoided.

Comment: Thanks a lot, it worked. Now I get another error, `Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#21>", line 1, in <module>
    lib = ctypes.WinDLL('C:/Develop/test/SDKApplication/Debug/SDKCore.dll')
  File "C:\Python27\lib\ctypes\__init__.py", line 365, in __init__
    self._handle = _dlopen(self._name, mode)
WindowsError: [Error 193] %1 is not a valid Win32 application`, but I think this might be due to the fact that my python is 32bit, and the dll 64.