# How to convert large .sav file into csv file

Tags: python, csv, spss

I am trying to convert a big ~2GB SPSS (.SAV) file into CSV using Python.

If there was a file which size < 500MB, there is no problem doing the following:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_spss('stdFile.sav')
df.to_csv("stdFile.csv", encoding = "utf-8-sig")
```

but in this case, i got a MemoryError...

Iam looking forward solutions, not necessarily in Python. But I don't have a SPSS license, so I must transform the file with another tool.

Comment: can you share some lines from you `sav file ` ?

Comment: This may be helpful: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yPaPZDg6JAA [YouTube - Convert SPSS (.sav) to Text (.csv)]

Comment: If you're comfortable with `R`, you can use the packages `haven` or `foreign` to read in the .sav file, and then you can use `base R` or the `xlsx` package to write out a .csv

Comment: I just tried your options, using R:
library(foreign)
write.table(read.spss("inputfile.sav"), file="outputfile.csv", quote = FALSE, sep = ",")

The problem now, is that i get a lot of white spaces! The original file was a .SAV(2GB) and the result is a .CSV(6GB)

I must read a little more about R and then report again, it's my first time using R-Gui. But anyway, i am now able to clear the CSV with python working with chunks. But i will give R another try

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use python's pyreadstat package to read the spss file in chunks, and save each chunk to the csv:

```
import pyreadstat
fpath = "path/to/stdFile.sav"
outpath = "stdFile.csv"
# chunksize determines how many rows to be read per chunk
reader = pyreadstat.read_file_in_chunks(pyreadstat.read_sav, fpath, chunksize= 10000)

cnt = 0
for df, meta in reader:
    # if on the first iteration write otherwise append
    if cnt>0:
        wmode = "a"
        header = False
    else:
        wmode = "w"
        header = True
    # write
    df.to_csv(outpath, mode=wmode, header=header)
    cnt+=1
```

more information here: https://github.com/Roche/pyreadstat#reading-rows-in-chunks

Comment: To read in chunks was the perfect solution, also the logic in this post is working perfectly. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

First import module savReaderWriter to convert .sav file into structured array then import module numpy to convert structured array into csv:

```
pip install savReaderWriter
```

[savReaderWriter](https://pypi.org/project/savReaderWriter/)

```
import savReaderWriter 
import numpy as np

reader_np = savReaderWriter.SavReaderNp("stdFile.sav")
array = reader_np.to_structured_array("outfile.dat") 
np.savetxt("stdFile.csv", array, delimiter=",")
reader_np.close()
```