# Read into Python a SPSS file

Tags: python, pandas

Is there a way to read a SPSS (.sav) file into a data-frame without downloading a 3rd party library (I then need to save it as a Stata (.dta) file?

I have looked up and tried:

```
import from rpy2.robjects import pandas2ri, r

filename = 'small test data.sav'
w = r('foreign::read.spss("%s", to.data.frame=TRUE)' % filename)
df = pandas2ri.ri2py(w)
df.head()
```

but I get a `ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified procedure could not be found` as I don't have the library.

Comment: I hear there is a [savReaderWriter][1] but that you would have to install. 

Have you tried saving your dataset as a .csv file and then processing it with Python? 


  [1]: https://pythonhosted.org/savReaderWriter/index.html

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there a Python module to open SPSS files?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14647006/is-there-a-python-module-to-open-spss-files)