# How to open or convert SPSS (.sav) file into CSV using Python - Pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, spss, spss-modeler

I have .sav file and i need to convert it into csv file.

I tried to use import **savReaderWriter** library but its not working. I am getting this error:

```
SPSSIOError: Problem opening file b'C:\\Users\\
```

I know in R it might be easier but i really need in Python. Any help?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is there a Python module to open SPSS files?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14647006/is-there-a-python-module-to-open-spss-files)

Answer (score 1):

Try with pyreadstat:

```
import pyreadstat

df, meta = pyreadstat.read_sav(r"C:\path\to\file.sav")

df.to_csv("mycsv.csv")
```

You have to install it with :

```
pip install pyreadstat
```

more information here:

https://github.com/Roche/pyreadstat