# Calling C functions from python code. Dll not working

Tags: python, c

I wrote below dll called djj.dll it has a file called try.cpp with following code

```
#include<stdio.h> 

int print(){ 

return 4; 

}
```

Now, i build this dll and go to python idle.

I type print windll.djj.print . It gives syntax error .WHY??

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I use a DLL from Python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/252417/how-can-i-use-a-dll-from-python)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Aaron Gallagher said, `print` is a Python keyword. Also it's unusual for a compiled DLL to use the standard Windows calling convention (i.e. windll). It's more likely to use [cdecl](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86_calling_conventions#cdecl) (i.e. cdll). Here's an approach that should work:

```
djj = ctypes.cdll.LoadLibrary('djj.dll')
my_print = getattr(djj, 'print')
x = my_print() #x is 4
```

Answer (score 0):

`print` is a keyword in python 2.x. You can't use it as an attribute name.