# Callback from python

Tags: callback

After reading a lot from this wonderful web, I need some help.

I have this function (in a dll):

```
kvStatus kvSetNotifyCallback  ( const int  hnd, kvCallback_t  callback,  void *  context,  
  unsigned int  notifyFlags);
```

How to call this function from Python?

I tried:

```
kvSetNotifyCallback(c_int(hnd1),c_void_p(self.can_rx()),None, c_int(canNOTIFY_RX))

def can_rx(self):

        print("OK")
```

The function can_rx does execute only once. Any suggestions? Thank you very much.
MM

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/252417/how-can-i-use-a-dll-from-python

Comment: Are you supposed to be calling it? `,c_void_p(self.can_rx())`

Answer (score 0):

first thing:

The argtypes of ctypes WINFUCNTYPE or CFUNCTYPE should be a c_void_p

The argtypes of fucntion which you are defining should be py_object instead of a c_void_p
so that you can pass objects of structures and arrays as well.

then in the callback fucntion cast the void_p data as 
`ct.cast(userdata,ct.py_object).value`

second thing:

code running only once: put a return value at bottom of the code.
return 1 or return TRUE

example:

```
CALLBACKFUNC = WINFUNCTYPE("returnvalue",c_int,c_void_p)

kvSetNotifyCallback.argtypes = [c_int,CALLBACKFUNC,py_object,c_uint]
```

then in the fucntion:

```
def can_rx(arg1,arg2):
     arg3 = cast(arg2,py_object).value #yields object value
     print arg1
     print arg3
     return 1    #for continuing execution
```

The CALLBACK FUNCTION can_rx should be called at CALLBACKFUNC(can_rx), the data to be passed along with arg1 should be passed at py_object position.

so you should call your callback as:

```
kvSetNotifyCallback(somevalue,CALLBACKFUC(can_rx),arg2,canNOTIFY_RX)
```

arg2 is the value to be passed to the callback func can_rx

can_rx can be defined as a global function also.