# Get Process Handles by Process Name

Tags: python, windows

Is there a way to get the list of Open Handles of a process in windows through python. I have able to find the solution in C/C++ through system calls but I have to do it in Python. Can Win32api help ??

Comment: Are you spawning those processes or do you mean just any process running ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/252417/how-can-i-use-a-dll-from-python

Comment: The `ctypes` module lets you make system calls in Python.

Comment: Well, I want to get the handles for any process. I have the list of all processes running on a system and want to get the handles for each of them.

Answer (score 0):

Use the [ctypes](http://docs.python.org/2/library/ctypes.html) import, then you can do the same things (mostly) you can in C, but with Python.