# How to use the Windows CryptoAPI from Python?

Tags: python, windows, cryptoapi

I am looking at using the Windows CryptoAPI from Python, but I can't find any existing modules for it - the win32crypt module that comes as part of the win32all suite only exposes a couple of high level functions that are of no use to me.

Are there any existing modules that wrap the CryptoAPI?  Searching PyPi has come up with zip.   Failing that example code on calling the API from ctypes, cython etc would be useful.

Comment: which pieces of the cryptoapi do you need/want?

Comment: @Woot4Moo:  I need it for creating keys and encrypting blocks of data using the low level API - CryptGenKey, CryptEncrypt, CryptDecrypt etc.  Also for finding out what algorithms are supported by each end.

Answer (score 1):

This : 
[How can I use a DLL file from Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/252417/how-can-i-use-a-dll-from-python) 
+ Getting the addresses of the functions you need from Crypt32.dll should work.