# Calling DLL from Python 3.4

Tags: c#, python, .net, dll

I had a dll written in C.   So for a C# application, I wrote a .cs wrapper that worked in calling the dll functions..

Now I have a C# dll and need to call the functions using python 3.4 (LoadLibrary).  What would be the preferred route of doing this

1) convert the C# dll code into C and make a new c-style dll (with exports).
2) Create some kind of wrapper in python that allows it to see the C# dll functions as-is?  ( if possible)
3) Both Python for .Net and IronPython don't seem to be actively maintained anymore (The windows installer shows python 2.7).   Is there a better alternative?

Comment: Take a look at `ctypes.windll`

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/252417/how-can-i-use-a-dll-from-python) on stack overflow.It tells how to use ctypes.It describes the ctypes.WinDLL command for including the required dll.You can set up prototype and parameters for the desired function call using `ctypes.WINFUNCTYPE`.