# Can I invoke a Python script from a Windows DLL?

Tags: python, windows, dll

We would like to invoke a Python application from within ZBrush, which has a very limited API. One option is the [FileExecute](http://docs.pixologic.com/user-guide/customizing-zbrush/zscripting/command-reference/#FileExecute) command, which invokes a method from a Windows DLL as follows:

```
[FileExecute, PluginTest.dll, ShowMsg, "Hi There"]
# Executes the "ShowMsg" routine in "PluginTest.dll" passing it the string "Hi There"
```

Is there a DLL included in the Windows Python installation that we could use to invoke an arbitrary Python script?

```
[FileExecute, PythonWindows.dll, RunScript, "example.py"]
# Runs the "example.py" script (found on the PYTHONPATH)
```

If not, how would you create such a DLL?

Comment: kind of the opposite of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/252417/how-can-i-use-a-dll-file-from-python

Comment: another option in the ZBrush API is LaunchAppWithFile: http://docs.pixologic.com/user-guide/customizing-zbrush/zscripting/zfileutils/#launchApp