# Getting this error *** OSError: cannot load library C:\WINDOWS\libzsfc.dll: error 0xc1

Tags: python-2.7, python-cffi, cffile

I am trying to load a .dll file using python cffi library, but whiele I am trying to load it I am getting following error:-

```
    *** OSError: cannot load library C:\WINDOWS\libzsfc.dll: error 0xc1
```

I am using this

```
from cffi import FFI
ffi = FFI()
lib = ffi.dlopen("libzsfc.dll")
```

but this giving me error, I tried a lot to resolve this, but it remains same, please let me know if anyone faced same issue.

Comment: 0xC1: The specified module could not be found. Maybe the DLL depends on other libraries that could not be found...

Comment: I put all the dependent file in the same directory, still I am facing this error, do I need to set some kinds of path in environment?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you have to first register the dll in windows then load will work fine.

To register the same use command `regsvr32 <complete dll path>`

Use Regsvr32.exe from the %SystemRoot%\Syswow64 folder. For example, type the following commands to register the DLL:  cd \windows\syswow64  regsvr32 c:\filename.dll

Comment: I have followed this step, but It is not work... Any other idea?

Comment: Did you try the `ctypes` ?  For more info follow the link http://stackoverflow.com/a/252473

Comment: Both ctypes and cffi's ``dlopen`` function just call ``LoadLibrary()`` from the Windows API.  If you get an error in one, I bet you get the same error in the other.  I don't know Windows enough to help you fix it.  It can be something like trying to load a 32-bit DLL into a 64-bit Python or vice-versa, or something completely different.

Comment: btw I find the solution for this issue, python2.7.13 64 bit required to load dll file.

Answer (score 0):

Old question, but I just had the same issue. Fixed:

Super easy - reinstall tessaract. Head over to https://github.com/UB-Mannheim/tesseract/wiki. Get their installer. It'll have you uninstall the old version. Worked immediately for me.