# Install Python Packages in Azure ML?

Tags: python, azure, azure-machine-learning-service, cvxpy

Similar question as [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43176442/install-r-packages-in-azure-ml) but now on Python packages. Currently, the CVXPY is missing in Azure ML. I am also trying to get other solvers such as GLPK, CLP and COINMP working in Azure ML.

**How can I install Python packages in Azure ML?**

---

*Update about trying to install the Python packages not found in Azure ML.*

> I did as instructed by Peter Pan but I think the 32bits CVXPY files are wrong for the Anaconda 4 and Python 3.5 in Azure ML, logs and errors are [here](https://pastebin.com/zN5QrPtL).
>
> ```
> [Information]         Running with Python 3.5.1 |Anaconda 4.0.0 (64-bit)| (default, Feb 16 2016, 09:49:46) [MSC v.1900 64 bit (AMD64)]
> ```
>
> [image]
>
> [image]
>
> [image]

*Update 2 with win_amd64 files (paste [here](https://pastebin.com/tisWuP5C))*

> ```
> [Information]         Extracting Script Bundle.zip to .\Script Bundle
> [Information]         File Name                                             Modified             Size
> [Information]         cvxopt-1.1.9-cp35-cp35m-win_amd64.whl          2017-06-07 01:03:34      1972074
> [Information]         __MACOSX/                                      2017-06-07 01:26:28            0
> [Information]         __MACOSX/._cvxopt-1.1.9-cp35-cp35m-win_amd64.whl 2017-06-07 01:03:34          452
> [Information]         cvxpy-0.4.10-py3-none-any.whl                  2017-06-07 00:25:36       300880
> [Information]         __MACOSX/._cvxpy-0.4.10-py3-none-any.whl       2017-06-07 00:25:36          444
> [Information]         ecos-2.0.4-cp35-cp35m-win_amd64.whl            2017-06-07 01:03:40        56522
> [Information]         __MACOSX/._ecos-2.0.4-cp35-cp35m-win_amd64.whl 2017-06-07 01:03:40          450
> [Information]         numpy-1.13.0rc2+mkl-cp35-cp35m-win_amd64.whl   2017-06-07 01:25:02    127909457
> [Information]         __MACOSX/._numpy-1.13.0rc2+mkl-cp35-cp35m-win_amd64.whl 2017-06-07 01:25:02          459
> [Information]         scipy-0.19.0-cp35-cp35m-win_amd64.whl          2017-06-07 01:05:12     12178932
> [Information]         __MACOSX/._scipy-0.19.0-cp35-cp35m-win_amd64.whl 2017-06-07 01:05:12          452
> [Information]         scs-1.2.6-cp35-cp35m-win_amd64.whl             2017-06-07 01:03:34        78653
> [Information]         __MACOSX/._scs-1.2.6-cp35-cp35m-win_amd64.whl  2017-06-07 01:03:34          449
> [Information]         [ READING ] 0:00:00
> [Information]         Input pandas.DataFrame #1:
> [Information]         Empty DataFrame
> [Information]         Columns: [1]
> [Information]         Index: []
> [Information]         [ EXECUTING ] 0:00:00
> [Information]         [ WRITING ] 0:00:00
> ```
>
> where `import cvxpy`, `import cvxpy-0.4.10-py3-none-any.whl` or `cvxpy-0.4.10-py3-none-any` do not work so
>
> **How can I use the following wheel files downloaded from [here](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/%7Egohlke/pythonlibs/#cvxpy) to use the external Python packages not found in Azure ML?**

*Update about permission problem about importing cvxpy (paste [here](https://pastebin.com/3kTKgLfc))*

> ```
>  [Error]         ImportError: No module named 'canonInterface'
> ```
>
> where the ZIP Bundle is organised a bit differently, the content of each wheel downloaded to a folder and the content having all zipped as a ZIP Bundle.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the [`Limitations`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/machine-learning/machine-learning-execute-python-scripts#limitations) and [`Technical Notes`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dn955437.aspx#Anchor_3) of `Execute Python Script` tutorial, the only way to add custom Python modules is via the zip file mechanism to package the modules and all dependencies.

For example to install `CVXPY`, as below.

1. Download the wheel file of [`CVXPY`](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#cvxpy) and its dependencies like [`CVXOPT`](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#cvxopt).
2. Decompress these wheel files, and package these files in the path `cvxpy` and `cvxopt`, etc as a zipped file with your script.
3. Upload the zip file as a dataset and use it as the script bundle.

If you were using IPython, you also can try to install the Python Package via the code `!pip install cvxpy`.

And there are some similar SO threads which may be helpful for you, as below.

1. [Azure ML Python with Script Bundle cannot import module](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44285641/azure-ml-python-with-script-bundle-cannot-import-module)
2. [How to install a Python package from within IPython?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8663046/how-to-install-a-python-package-from-within-ipython)

Hope it helps.

---

Update:

For IPython interface of Azure ML, you move to the `NOTEBOOKS` tab to create a notebook via `ADD TO PROJECT` button at the bottom of the page, as the figure below.

[image]

Or you can directly login to the website `https://notebooks.azure.com` to use it.

Comment: Does this mean That external packages work better with R than Python? In R, we can use intall.package option for zipped packsges while in Python, we can only use them as scripts without installaation in Azure ML.

Comment: @hhh It's a limitaion for Execute Python Script module on Azure ML now, especially for those packages required compiler when installing.

Comment: @hhh For IPython interface of Azure ML, I updated in my post.

Comment: @hhh Sure, it seems to be easier for using external package in R environment on Azure ML. And please install these WIN32 packages in Azure ML.

Comment: @hhh Yes, you are right, 64-bit version based on your error message.

Comment: @hhh The error `ImportError: No module named 'canonInterface'` means that here require `canonInterface`, but not exists. The `canonInterface` exists in the package [`cvxcanon`](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#cvxcanon), please also package it into your zip file.

Comment: Thank you for helping, I finally got this working [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44401423/164148). It was not that straightforward. I had to create a new directory for the content of the ecos.wheel package and I had to include multiprocess and CVXCanon besides all other dependencies. I provided screenshot about all included in the ZIP Bundle.

Answer (score 1):

*I will demo Peter Pan's answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44383310/164148) and I show first a working experiment with external package. Building the ZIP Bundle for the external package CVXPY was not that straight-forward but educational.*

---

**Demo about external package using ZIP Bundle in Azure ML**

This is a working example about using an additional package in Python Script module provided by Smit Shah

> https://gallery.cortanaintelligence.com/Experiment/Python-additional-package

where

[image]

```
[Information]         Extracting Script Bundle.zip to .\Script Bundle
[Information]         File Name                                             Modified             Size
[Information]         adal/__init__.py                               2017-05-01 10:03:04         1822
[Information]         adal/__init__.pyc                              2017-05-01 10:03:12          629
[Information]         adal/adal_error.py                             2017-05-01 10:03:04         1553
[Information]         adal/adal_error.pyc                            2017-05-01 10:03:12          685
[Information]         adal/argument.py                               2017-05-01 10:03:04         2023
[Information]         adal/argument.pyc                              2017-05-01 10:03:12          837
[Information]         adal/authentication_context.py                 2017-05-01 10:03:04        13766
[Information]         adal/authentication_context.pyc                2017-05-01 10:03:12        14198
[Information]         adal/authentication_parameters.py              2017-05-01 10:03:04         8195
[Information]         adal/authentication_parameters.pyc             2017-05-01 10:03:12         4820
[Information]         adal/authority.py                              2017-05-01 10:03:04         6908
[Information]         adal/authority.pyc                             2017-05-01 10:03:12         6091
[Information]         adal/cache_driver.py                           2017-05-01 10:03:04         9773
[Information]         adal/cache_driver.pyc                          2017-05-01 10:03:12         9293
[Information]         adal/code_request.py                           2017-05-01 10:03:04         2744
[Information]         adal/code_request.pyc                          2017-05-01 10:03:12         2225
[Information]         adal/constants.py                              2017-05-01 10:03:04         7359
[Information]         adal/constants.pyc                             2017-05-01 10:03:12         9305
[Information]         adal/log.py                                    2017-05-01 10:03:04         4058
[Information]         adal/log.pyc                                   2017-05-01 10:03:12         3699
[Information]         adal/mex.py                                    2017-05-01 10:03:04        11186
[Information]         adal/mex.pyc                                   2017-05-01 10:03:12         8804
[Information]         adal/oauth2_client.py                          2017-05-01 10:03:04        14196
[Information]         adal/oauth2_client.pyc                         2017-05-01 10:03:12        11619
[Information]         adal/self_signed_jwt.py                        2017-05-01 10:03:04         4823
[Information]         adal/self_signed_jwt.pyc                       2017-05-01 10:03:12         5301
[Information]         adal/token_cache.py                            2017-05-01 10:03:04         4761
[Information]         adal/token_cache.pyc                           2017-05-01 10:03:12         4883
[Information]         adal/token_request.py                          2017-05-01 10:03:04        17703
[Information]         adal/token_request.pyc                         2017-05-01 10:03:12        15096
[Information]         adal/user_realm.py                             2017-05-01 10:03:04         6362
[Information]         adal/user_realm.pyc                            2017-05-01 10:03:12         5325
[Information]         adal/util.py                                   2017-05-01 10:03:04         3567
[Information]         adal/util.pyc                                  2017-05-01 10:03:12         2723
[Information]         adal/wstrust_request.py                        2017-05-01 10:03:04         8402
[Information]         adal/wstrust_request.pyc                       2017-05-01 10:03:12         6816
[Information]         adal/wstrust_response.py                       2017-05-01 10:03:04         8751
[Information]         adal/wstrust_response.pyc                      2017-05-01 10:03:12         5467
[Information]         adal/xmlutil.py                                2017-05-01 10:03:04         2806
[Information]         adal/xmlutil.pyc                               2017-05-01 10:03:12         2309
[Information]         cryptography/__about__.py                      2017-04-27 17:51:38          817
[Information]         cryptography/__about__.pyc                     2017-04-27 17:51:50          892
[Information]         cryptography/__init__.py                       2017-04-27 17:51:38          829
[Information]         cryptography/__init__.pyc                      2017-04-27 17:51:50          962
[Information]         cryptography/exceptions.py                     2017-04-27 17:51:38         1234
[Information]         cryptography/exceptions.pyc                    2017-04-27 17:51:50         3406
[Information]         cryptography/fernet.py                         2017-04-27 17:51:38         4305
[Information]         cryptography/fernet.pyc                        2017-04-27 17:51:50         5670
[Information]         cryptography/hazmat/                           2017-04-27 17:51:50            0
[Information]         cryptography/hazmat/__init__.py                2017-04-27 17:51:38          483
[Information]         cryptography/hazmat/__init__.pyc               2017-04-27 17:51:50          560
[Information]         cryptography/hazmat/backends/                  2017-04-27 17:51:50            0
[Information]         cryptography/hazmat/backends/__init__.py       2017-04-27 17:51:38         2403
[Information]         cryptography/hazmat/backends/__init__.pyc      2017-04-27 17:51:50         1783
[Information]         cryptography/hazmat/backends/commoncrypto/     2017-04-27 17:51:50            0
[Information]         cryptography/hazmat/backends/commoncrypto/__init__.py 2017-04-27 17:51:38          341
[Information]         cryptography/hazmat/backends/commoncrypto/__init__.pyc 2017-04-27 17:51:50          448
[Information]         cryptography/hazmat/backends/commoncrypto/backend.py 2017-04-27 17:51:38         8840
[Information]         cryptography/hazmat/backends/commoncrypto/backend.pyc 2017-04-27 17:51:50         9402
[Information]         cryptography/hazmat/backends/commoncrypto/ciphers.py 2017-04-27 17:51:38         9362
[Information]         cryptography/hazmat/backends/commoncrypto/ciphers.pyc 2017-04-27 17:51:50         8265
[Information]         cryptography/hazmat/backends/commoncrypto/hashes.py 2017-04-27 17:51:38         2040
[Information]         cryptography/hazmat/backends/commoncrypto/hashes.pyc 2017-04-27 17:51:50         2884
[Information]         cryptography/hazmat/backends/commoncrypto/hmac.py 2017-04-27 17:51:38         2188
[Information]         cryptography/hazmat/backends/commoncrypto/hmac.pyc 2017-04-27 17:51:50         3231
[Information]         cryptography/hazmat/backends/interfaces.py     2017-04-27 17:51:38        10493
[Information]         cryptography/hazmat/backends/interfaces.pyc    2017-04-27 17:51:50        21555
[Information]         cryptography/hazmat/backends/multibackend.py   2017-04-27 17:51:38        19700
[Information]         cryptography/hazmat/backends/multibackend.pyc  2017-04-27 17:51:50        25269
[Information]         cryptography/hazmat/backends/openssl/          2017-04-27 17:51:50            0
[Information]         cryptography/hazmat/backends/openssl/__init__.py 2017-04-27 17:51:38          336
[Information]         cryptography/hazmat/backends/openssl/__init__.pyc 2017-04-27 17:51:50          438
[Information]         cryptography/hazmat/backends/openssl/backend.py 2017-04-27 17:51:38        68646
[Information]         cryptography/hazmat/backends/openssl/backend.pyc 2017-04-27 17:51:50        64293
[Information]         cryptography/hazmat/backends/openssl/ciphers.py 2017-04-27 17:51:38         7665
[Information]         cryptography/hazmat/backends/openssl/ciphers.pyc 2017-04-27 17:51:50         6101
[Information]         cryptography/hazmat/backends/openssl/cmac.py   2017-04-27 17:51:38         2797
[Information]         cryptography/hazmat/backends/openssl/cmac.pyc  2017-04-27 17:51:50         3668
[Information]         cryptography/hazmat/backends/openssl/decode_asn1.py 2017-04-27 17:51:38        29210
[Information]         cryptography/hazmat/backends/openssl/decode_asn1.pyc 2017-04-27 17:51:50        28941
[Information]         cryptography/hazmat/backends/openssl/dh.py     2017-04-27 17:51:38         9945
[Information]         cryptography/hazmat/backends/openssl/dh.pyc    2017-04-27 17:51:50        10966
[Information]         cryptography/hazmat/backends/openssl/dsa.py    2017-04-27 17:51:38        10044
[Information]         cryptography/hazmat/backends/openssl/dsa.pyc   2017-04-27 17:51:50        12467
[Information]         cryptography/hazmat/backends/openssl/ec.py     2017-04-27 17:51:38         9914
[Information]         cryptography/hazmat/backends/openssl/ec.pyc    2017-04-27 17:51:50        12615
[Information]         cryptography/hazmat/backends/openssl/encode_asn1.py 2017-04-27 17:51:38        22285
[Information]         cryptography/hazmat/backends/openssl/encode_asn1.pyc 2017-04-27 17:51:50        22267
[Information]         cryptography/hazmat/backends/openssl/hashes.py 2017-04-27 17:51:38         2532
[Information]         cryptography/hazmat/backends/openssl/hashes.pyc 2017-04-27 17:51:50         3185
[Information]         cryptography/hazmat/backends/openssl/hmac.py   2017-04-27 17:51:38         2980
[Information]         cryptography/hazmat/backends/openssl/hmac.pyc  2017-04-27 17:51:50         3732
[Information]         cryptography/hazmat/backends/openssl/rsa.py    2017-04-27 17:51:38        18610
[Information]         cryptography/hazmat/backends/openssl/rsa.pyc   2017-04-27 17:51:50        17931
[Information]         cryptography/hazmat/backends/openssl/utils.py  2017-04-27 17:51:38          862
[Information]         cryptography/hazmat/backends/openssl/utils.pyc 2017-04-27 17:51:50         1088
[Information]         cryptography/hazmat/backends/openssl/x509.py   2017-04-27 17:51:38        15804
[Information]         cryptography/hazmat/backends/openssl/x509.pyc  2017-04-27 17:51:50        23091
[Information]         cryptography/hazmat/bindings/                  2017-04-27 17:51:50            0
[Information]         cryptography/hazmat/bindings/__init__.py       2017-04-27 17:51:38          246
[Information]         cryptography/hazmat/bindings/__init__.pyc      2017-04-27 17:51:50          313
[Information]         cryptography/hazmat/bindings/_constant_time.pyd 2017-04-27 17:51:38         8192
[Information]         cryptography/hazmat/bindings/_openssl.pyd      2017-04-27 17:51:38      2754560
[Information]         cryptography/hazmat/bindings/_padding.pyd      2017-04-27 17:51:38         8704
[Information]         cryptography/hazmat/bindings/commoncrypto/     2017-04-27 17:51:50            0
[Information]         cryptography/hazmat/bindings/commoncrypto/__init__.py 2017-04-27 17:51:38          246
[Information]         cryptography/hazmat/bindings/commoncrypto/__init__.pyc 2017-04-27 17:51:50          326
[Information]         cryptography/hazmat/bindings/commoncrypto/binding.py 2017-04-27 17:51:38          410
[Information]         cryptography/hazmat/bindings/commoncrypto/binding.pyc 2017-04-27 17:51:50          785
[Information]         cryptography/hazmat/bindings/openssl/          2017-04-27 17:51:50            0
[Information]         cryptography/hazmat/bindings/openssl/__init__.py 2017-04-27 17:51:38          246
[Information]         cryptography/hazmat/bindings/openssl/__init__.pyc 2017-04-27 17:51:50          321
[Information]         cryptography/hazmat/bindings/openssl/_conditional.py 2017-04-27 17:51:38         8854
[Information]         cryptography/hazmat/bindings/openssl/_conditional.pyc 2017-04-27 17:51:50         8138
[Information]         cryptography/hazmat/bindings/openssl/binding.py 2017-04-27 17:51:38         5067
[Information]         cryptography/hazmat/bindings/openssl/binding.pyc 2017-04-27 17:51:50         5118
[Information]         cryptography/hazmat/primitives/                2017-04-27 17:51:50            0
[Information]         cryptography/hazmat/primitives/__init__.py     2017-04-27 17:51:38          246
[Information]         cryptography/hazmat/primitives/__init__.pyc    2017-04-27 17:51:50          315
[Information]         cryptography/hazmat/primitives/asymmetric/     2017-04-27 17:51:50            0
[Information]         cryptography/hazmat/primitives/asymmetric/__init__.py 2017-04-27 17:51:38         1020
[Information]         cryptography/hazmat/primitives/asymmetric/__init__.pyc 2017-04-27 17:51:50         2305
[Information]         cryptography/hazmat/primitives/asymmetric/dh.py 2017-04-27 17:51:38         5093
[Information]         cryptography/hazmat/primitives/asymmetric/dh.pyc 2017-04-27 17:51:50        10298
[Information]         cryptography/hazmat/primitives/asymmetric/dsa.py 2017-04-27 17:51:38         6890
[Information]         cryptography/hazmat/primitives/asymmetric/dsa.pyc 2017-04-27 17:51:50        13468
[Information]         cryptography/hazmat/primitives/asymmetric/ec.py 2017-04-27 17:51:38         9570
[Information]         cryptography/hazmat/primitives/asymmetric/ec.pyc 2017-04-27 17:51:50        18550
[Information]         cryptography/hazmat/primitives/asymmetric/padding.py 2017-04-27 17:51:38         2261
[Information]         cryptography/hazmat/primitives/asymmetric/padding.pyc 2017-04-27 17:51:50         4322
[Information]         cryptography/hazmat/primitives/asymmetric/rsa.py 2017-04-27 17:51:38        10226
[Information]         cryptography/hazmat/primitives/asymmetric/rsa.pyc 2017-04-27 17:51:50        15084
[Information]         cryptography/hazmat/primitives/asymmetric/utils.py 2017-04-27 17:51:38         1704
[Information]         cryptography/hazmat/primitives/asymmetric/utils.pyc 2017-04-27 17:51:50         2984
[Information]         cryptography/hazmat/primitives/ciphers/        2017-04-27 17:51:50            0
[Information]         cryptography/hazmat/primitives/ciphers/__init__.py 2017-04-27 17:51:38          574
[Information]         cryptography/hazmat/primitives/ciphers/__init__.pyc 2017-04-27 17:51:50          654
[Information]         cryptography/hazmat/primitives/ciphers/algorithms.py 2017-04-27 17:51:38         3424
[Information]         cryptography/hazmat/primitives/ciphers/algorithms.pyc 2017-04-27 17:51:50         7930
[Information]         cryptography/hazmat/primitives/ciphers/base.py 2017-04-27 17:51:38         7663
[Information]         cryptography/hazmat/primitives/ciphers/base.pyc 2017-04-27 17:51:50        12557
[Information]         cryptography/hazmat/primitives/ciphers/modes.py 2017-04-27 17:51:38         5517
[Information]         cryptography/hazmat/primitives/ciphers/modes.pyc 2017-04-27 17:51:50         9165
[Information]         cryptography/hazmat/primitives/cmac.py         2017-04-27 17:51:38         2235
[Information]         cryptography/hazmat/primitives/cmac.pyc        2017-04-27 17:51:50         3192
[Information]         cryptography/hazmat/primitives/constant_time.py 2017-04-27 17:51:38          798
[Information]         cryptography/hazmat/primitives/constant_time.pyc 2017-04-27 17:51:50         1237
[Information]         cryptography/hazmat/primitives/hashes.py       2017-04-27 17:51:38         5081
[Information]         cryptography/hazmat/primitives/hashes.pyc      2017-04-27 17:51:50         9263
[Information]         cryptography/hazmat/primitives/hmac.py         2017-04-27 17:51:38         2353
[Information]         cryptography/hazmat/primitives/hmac.pyc        2017-04-27 17:51:50         3322
[Information]         cryptography/hazmat/primitives/interfaces/     2017-04-27 17:51:50            0
[Information]         cryptography/hazmat/primitives/interfaces/__init__.py 2017-04-27 17:51:38          884
[Information]         cryptography/hazmat/primitives/interfaces/__init__.pyc 2017-04-27 17:51:50         1961
[Information]         cryptography/hazmat/primitives/kdf/            2017-04-27 17:51:50            0
[Information]         cryptography/hazmat/primitives/kdf/__init__.py 2017-04-27 17:51:38          771
[Information]         cryptography/hazmat/primitives/kdf/__init__.pyc 2017-04-27 17:51:50         1473
[Information]         cryptography/hazmat/primitives/kdf/concatkdf.py 2017-04-27 17:51:38         4109
[Information]         cryptography/hazmat/primitives/kdf/concatkdf.pyc 2017-04-27 17:51:50         5908
[Information]         cryptography/hazmat/primitives/kdf/hkdf.py     2017-04-27 17:51:38         3674
[Information]         cryptography/hazmat/primitives/kdf/hkdf.pyc    2017-04-27 17:51:50         4986
[Information]         cryptography/hazmat/primitives/kdf/kbkdf.py    2017-04-27 17:51:38         5017
[Information]         cryptography/hazmat/primitives/kdf/kbkdf.pyc   2017-04-27 17:51:50         5610
[Information]         cryptography/hazmat/primitives/kdf/pbkdf2.py   2017-04-27 17:51:38         2185
[Information]         cryptography/hazmat/primitives/kdf/pbkdf2.pyc  2017-04-27 17:51:50         2813
[Information]         cryptography/hazmat/primitives/kdf/scrypt.py   2017-04-27 17:51:38         2252
[Information]         cryptography/hazmat/primitives/kdf/scrypt.pyc  2017-04-27 17:51:50         2957
[Information]         cryptography/hazmat/primitives/kdf/x963kdf.py  2017-04-27 17:51:38         2363
[Information]         cryptography/hazmat/primitives/kdf/x963kdf.pyc 2017-04-27 17:51:50         3296
[Information]         cryptography/hazmat/primitives/keywrap.py      2017-04-27 17:51:38         3050
[Information]         cryptography/hazmat/primitives/keywrap.pyc     2017-04-27 17:51:50         3136
[Information]         cryptography/hazmat/primitives/padding.py      2017-04-27 17:51:38         5736
[Information]         cryptography/hazmat/primitives/padding.pyc     2017-04-27 17:51:50        10471
[Information]         cryptography/hazmat/primitives/serialization.py 2017-04-27 17:51:38         5288
[Information]         cryptography/hazmat/primitives/serialization.pyc 2017-04-27 17:51:50         8668
[Information]         cryptography/hazmat/primitives/twofactor/      2017-04-27 17:51:50            0
[Information]         cryptography/hazmat/primitives/twofactor/__init__.py 2017-04-27 17:51:38          288
[Information]         cryptography/hazmat/primitives/twofactor/__init__.pyc 2017-04-27 17:51:50          607
[Information]         cryptography/hazmat/primitives/twofactor/hotp.py 2017-04-27 17:51:38         2589
[Information]         cryptography/hazmat/primitives/twofactor/hotp.pyc 2017-04-27 17:51:50         3808
[Information]         cryptography/hazmat/primitives/twofactor/totp.py 2017-04-27 17:51:38         1594
[Information]         cryptography/hazmat/primitives/twofactor/totp.pyc 2017-04-27 17:51:50         2637
[Information]         cryptography/hazmat/primitives/twofactor/utils.py 2017-04-27 17:51:38          954
[Information]         cryptography/hazmat/primitives/twofactor/utils.pyc 2017-04-27 17:51:50         1208
[Information]         cryptography/utils.py                          2017-04-27 17:51:38         4130
[Information]         cryptography/utils.pyc                         2017-04-27 17:51:50         6969
[Information]         cryptography/x509/                             2017-04-27 17:51:50            0
[Information]         cryptography/x509/__init__.py                  2017-04-27 17:51:38         6857
[Information]         cryptography/x509/__init__.pyc                 2017-04-27 17:51:50         6944
[Information]         cryptography/x509/base.py                      2017-04-27 17:51:38        23315
[Information]         cryptography/x509/base.pyc                     2017-04-27 17:51:50        31205
[Information]         cryptography/x509/extensions.py                2017-04-27 17:51:38        37228
[Information]         cryptography/x509/extensions.pyc               2017-04-27 17:51:50        59587
[Information]         cryptography/x509/general_name.py              2017-04-27 17:51:38         7519
[Information]         cryptography/x509/general_name.pyc             
...
2017-04-27 11:28:02        21986
[Information]         dateutil/relativedelta.pyc                     2017-04-27 11:28:06        17516
[Information]         dateutil/rrule.py                              2017-04-27 11:28:02        61792
[Information]         dateutil/rrule.pyc                             2017-04-27 11:28:06        48786
[Information]         dateutil/tz/                                   2017-04-27 11:28:06            0
[Information]         dateutil/tz/__init__.py                        2017-04-27 11:28:02          145
[Information]         dateutil/tz/__init__.pyc                       2017-04-27 11:28:06          379
[Information]         dateutil/tz/_common.py                         2017-04-27 11:28:02        11744
[Information]         dateutil/tz/_common.pyc                        2017-04-27 11:28:06        13900
[Information]         dateutil/tz/tz.py                              2017-04-27 11:28:02        48924
[Information]         dateutil/tz/tz.pyc                             2017-04-27 11:28:06        44590
[Information]         dateutil/tz/win.py                             2017-04-27 11:28:02        11466
[Information]         dateutil/tz/win.pyc                            2017-04-27 11:28:06        12475
[Information]         dateutil/tzwin.py                              2017-04-27 11:28:02           58
[Information]         dateutil/tzwin.pyc                             2017-04-27 11:28:06          211
[Information]         dateutil/zoneinfo/                             2017-04-27 11:28:06            0
[Information]         dateutil/zoneinfo/__init__.py                  2017-04-27 11:28:02         6810
[Information]         dateutil/zoneinfo/__init__.pyc                 2017-04-27 11:28:06         7654
[Information]         dateutil/zoneinfo/dateutil-zoneinfo.tar.gz     2017-04-27 11:28:02       139671
[Information]         dateutil/zoneinfo/rebuild.py                   2017-04-27 11:28:02         1688
[Information]         dateutil/zoneinfo/rebuild.pyc                  2017-04-27 11:28:06         2239
[Information]         jwt/__init__.py                                2017-06-06 14:51:08          738
[Information]         jwt/__init__.pyc                               2017-06-06 14:51:08         1177
[Information]         jwt/__main__.py                                2017-06-06 14:51:08         3585
[Information]         jwt/__main__.pyc                               2017-06-06 14:51:08         3120
[Information]         jwt/algorithms.py                              2017-06-06 14:51:08        13758
[Information]         jwt/algorithms.pyc                             2017-06-06 14:51:08        14450
[Information]         jwt/api_jws.py                                 2017-06-06 14:51:08         7133
[Information]         jwt/api_jws.pyc                                2017-06-06 14:51:08         7462
[Information]         jwt/api_jwt.py                                 2017-06-06 14:51:08         6547
[Information]         jwt/api_jwt.pyc                                2017-06-06 14:51:08         6842
[Information]         jwt/compat.py                                  2017-06-06 14:51:08         1784
[Information]         jwt/compat.pyc                                 2017-06-06 14:51:08         2253
[Information]         jwt/contrib/                                   2017-06-06 14:51:08            0
[Information]         jwt/contrib/__init__.py                        2017-06-06 14:51:08            0
[Information]         jwt/contrib/__init__.pyc                       2017-06-06 14:51:08          163
[Information]         jwt/contrib/algorithms/                        2017-06-06 14:51:08            0
[Information]         jwt/contrib/algorithms/__init__.py             2017-06-06 14:51:08            0
[Information]         jwt/contrib/algorithms/__init__.pyc            2017-06-06 14:51:08          174
[Information]         jwt/contrib/algorithms/py_ecdsa.py             2017-06-06 14:51:08         1771
[Information]         jwt/contrib/algorithms/py_ecdsa.pyc            2017-06-06 14:51:08         2406
[Information]         jwt/contrib/algorithms/pycrypto.py             2017-06-06 14:51:08         1250
[Information]         jwt/contrib/algorithms/pycrypto.pyc            2017-06-06 14:51:08         2325
[Information]         jwt/exceptions.py                              2017-06-06 14:51:08          841
[Information]         jwt/exceptions.pyc                             2017-06-06 14:51:08         2777
[Information]         jwt/utils.py                                   2017-06-06 14:51:08         2629
[Information]         jwt/utils.pyc                                  2017-06-06 14:51:08         4204
```

so the ZIP bundle has been done in a specific way such that packages' dist-info folders are removed and only the folders having the exact name of the package is included

[image]

by which I was able to run `import cvxpy`, notice that new packages `multiplocess` and `CVXCanon` are included. Yet in solving a problem, I got error with `ecos` module missing next. So I created a new directory `ecos` for all files found in the original `ecos.*.wheel` package so the updated ZIP Bundle looks like this

[image]

by which I was able to solve the following convex optimisation problem with DCP tool called CVXPY.

[image]

*Code inside Python Script module that solves an optimisation problem with CVXPY in Azure ML*

```
import pandas as pd
from cvxpy import *
import numpy

def azureml_main(dataframe1 = None, dataframe2 = None):

    # Problem data.
    m = 30
    n = 20
    numpy.random.seed(1)
    A = numpy.random.randn(m, n)
    b = numpy.random.randn(m)

    # Construct the problem.
    x = Variable(n)
    objective = Minimize(sum_squares(A*x - b))
    constraints = [0 <= x, x <= 1]
    prob = Problem(objective, constraints)

    # The optimal objective is returned by prob.solve().
    result = prob.solve()
    # The optimal value for x is stored in x.value.
    #print x.value
    # The optimal Lagrange multiplier for a constraint
    # is stored in constraint.dual_value.
    #print constraints[0].dual_value

    dataframe1=pd.DataFrame(numpy.zeros(1))
    dataframe1[0][0]=result

    # Return value must be of a sequence of pandas.DataFrame
    return dataframe1,
```

**Further reading**

1. Notice that the code creates a Panda DataFrame with size one zero matrix, there may be more elegant way to do it, more in
   [Python Pandas DataFrame with only a single number stored?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44409066/python-pandas-dataframe-with-only-a-single-number-stored)

Answer (score 1):

Or just use something like this

```
import pip

# you can make this install from a local path if needed, and upload the binaries
def install(package):
    if hasattr(pip, 'main'):
        pip.main(['install', package])
    else:
        pip._internal.main(['install', package])

if __name__ == '__main__':
    try:
        import mymodule
    except:
        install('mymodule')
```

[Installing python module within code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12332975/installing-python-module-within-code)