# Python Pandas DataFrame with only a single number stored?

Tags: python, pandas, azure, azure-machine-learning-service

AzureML's Python Script module requires to return a Pandas DataFrame. I want to return only a value and I do this:

```
result=7
dataframe1=pd.DataFrame(numpy.zeros(1))
dataframe1[0][0]=result
```

by which I am able to return just a single value in Azure ML's Python Script module.

**What is a proper way to create a pandas DataFrame with a single value?**

Comment: the minimum would be `pd.DataFrame([result])`

Comment: @EdChum I tried that but it did not work in Azure ML, it complained something about the wrong type as a return type.

Comment: Well the only different here is that your version produces a df with dtype float, my snippet would preserve the result as `int`, does AzureML require floats? If so you can do `pd.DataFrame([result], dtype=float)`

Comment: @EdChum thank you, I tested it and it works!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following code should work:

```
import pandas as pd
def azureml_main(dataframe1 = None, dataframe2 = None):
    result = pd.DataFrame({'mycol': [123]})
    return result,
```

Answer (score 1):

As EdChum commented

```
dataframe1=pd.DataFrame([result], dtype=float)
```

and it works, tested, instead of

```
result=7
dataframe1=pd.DataFrame(numpy.zeros(1))
dataframe1[0][0]=result
```

where we don't need to use numpy to initiate the return value with zeroes.

*P.s. EdChum can make this his answer if he wants.*