# ImportError: No module named cassandra in Azure Machine Learning Studio

Tags: python, python-3.x, azure, cassandra, azure-machine-learning-service

I am trying to install python package cassandra driver in Azure Machine Learning studio. I am following this answer from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44371692/install-python-packages-in-azure-ml). Unfortunately i don't see any wheel file for cassandra-driver https://pypi.python.org/pypi/cassandra-driver/ so i downloaded the .tar file and converted to zip.

I included this .zip file as dataset and connected to python script

[image: jpg1]

But when i run it, it says No module named cassandra
[image: jpg2]

Does this work only with wheel file? Any solution is much appreciated.

I am using Python Version :  Anoconda 4.0/Python 3.5

Comment: Does pip installing the package not work?

Comment: I  don't know if pip install is used in Azure Machine Learning studio. Till now, i have seen examples using wheel file as .zip bundle and connect it to python script.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it working. Changed the folder inside .zip file to `"cassandra"` (just like cassandra package).

And in the Python script, i added

```
from cassandra import *
```