# Need to install python packages in Azure ML studio

Tags: python-3.x, azure, scikit-learn, azure-machine-learning-service, ml-studio

I am new to Azure ML studio and trying to run python script.

Currently I am working on Text analytics related code and as part of that I want to get the singular values of SVD decomposition something like below

```
        lsa=TruncatedSVD(algorithm='randomized',n_components=MaximumNumComponents,n_iter=20,random_state=42,tol=0.0)
        U = lsa.fit_transform(X)
        Sigma = lsa.singular_values_
```

Current version of scikit learn in Azure ML studio is 0.17 and singular values is part of higher versions of scikit learn like 0.20.

So I need to upgrade scikit learn package to 0.20. I tried downloading scikit learn 0.20 wheel file and zipped it and uploaded as dataset into Azure ML studio and connected [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yH3RO.png) but still getting error like below "

AttributeError: 'TruncatedSVD' object has no attribute 'singular_values_'
Process returned with non-zero exit code 1

Already referred to below questions as well

[Stackoverflow questions related to upgrade packages in Azure ML studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8663046/how-to-install-a-python-package-from-within-ipython)
[How can I install Python packages in Azure ML?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44371692/install-python-packages-in-azure-ml/44383310#44383310)

Answer (score 0):

Currently this is the limitation with Azure ML studio. The only way is to reach out to support who generates the necessary package and we can upload it to Azure ML Studio.