# How can install additional python packages in Azure Machine Learning Studio?

Tags: python, azure, jupyter-notebook, azure-machine-learning-service

Hey I am trying to install `dash` and `jupyter-dash` in Azure Machine Learning Studio (New- not classic). I opened terminal and installed them using `pip install` and they successully were installed upon checking with `pip freeze`. However when I open notebook I still get error:
`ModuleNotFoundError`.

Is there a way to add those missing libraries that I need in order to run the script in my notebook?

Comment: maybe run in notebook `!pip install`

Comment: did you restart the kernel?

Comment: also which module's aren't found?

Comment: You need to make sure these packages have been installed to the same conda environment as the kernel. By default, the Python 3.8 kernel should have a related azureml_py38. 
Use `conda env list` in the terminal to see your current conda env

Comment: `pip install ` worked for me not  `!pip install `

Answer (score 5):

You want to use `%pip install package` not `!pip install package`

Answer (score -1):

There are limitations when installing the additional Python packages in Azure ML Studio and therefore the only possible way to add custom python modules, you can zip all packages and modules.

For example, to install `cvxpy`,

1. Download wheel of cvpxy and the dependencies.
2. Decompress the files and package it in in cvpxy path as a zip file including script.
3. You can then upload the zip as data set.

If you are using IPython, you also can try to install the Python Package via the code !pip install cvxpy.

There are some similar SO threads which may be helpful for you, as below.

[Azure ML Python with Script Bundle cannot import module](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44285641/azure-ml-python-with-script-bundle-cannot-import-module)

[How to install a Python package from within IPython?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8663046/how-to-install-a-python-package-from-within-ipython)