# In Python, can I import a C# DLL if it's not directly in path?

Tags: python, dllimport

I am using pythonnet and clr to import a C# .DLL
Folder structure is like this:

```
|-- project
    |-- foo.py
    |-- folderWithDll
        |-- Common.Dll
        |-- example.py
```

If I am running cmd from the \\project folder, this will work:

```
from folderWithDll.example import *
```

But when I try this:

```
import clr
from folderWithDll.Common.APIs import *
```

I am met with the following error:

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'folderWithDll.Common'
```

However if I add folderWithDll to the path with:

```
sys.path.insert(0, os.getcwd()+'\\folderWithDll')
```

Then I can just do this and it will work:

```
from Common.APIs import *
```

Why can I not import the DLL unless I have its parent folder added to sys.path?

Thank you!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I use a DLL file from Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/252417/how-can-i-use-a-dll-file-from-python)

Comment: I don't think this is a duplicate, I'm asking specifically for importing a C# .dll, why do I need its direct parent folder?