# Is there a python module could sign and verify data by RSA key pair from certificate store?

Tags: python, cryptography, x509certificate, cryptoapi

I tried to sign and verify by C++ cryptoAPI and it works well. The cryptoAPI use the certificate from the store(Personal) on windows to do this. Could I do the same thing by python without export private key or input passphrase?

I tried pycrypto, oscrypto, wincertstore module, but they can't do this.

Comment: https://cryptography.io has all of the abilities of openssl and has a full suite of tools to work with x509 certs. Also 1) PyCrypto is deprecated; use PyCryptoDome instead. 2) This question is off topic which is why I must vote to close this.

Comment: @Legorooj I can't find the relative API to request the certificate from 'My' certificate store to sign and verify signature. Could you show me the page? And why this question is off topic?

Comment: My apologies I just re-read the question. `cryptography` doesn't support loading certs from the windows certificate store - but the `pywin32` module might do that for you, then you can use `cryptography` to manipulate the cert. The Q is off topic because it is `"Asking for ... software libraries or other off-site resources. This could lead to opinonated answers."` See [here](http://timgolden.me.uk/pywin32-docs/contents.html) for the `pywin32` docs.

Comment: I tried to use `pywin32`, it can open cert store, but there isn't an API to find the specific certificate I wanted. It's `CertFindCertificateInStore()` in CryptoAPI. Am i missing something?

Comment: Hmm. Just found that you can list all of the certs with the build in `ssl` lib; `ssl.enum_certificates(store_name)` where store name is `CA`, `ROOT`, or `MY`. I'm assuming the last on - would this help? it returns lists. You could search those and then load the cert out of the store?

Comment: @Legorooj That would of course not help with the signing part. Note that signing is not a function of the certificate. Microsoft however treats the private key within the store as *part of the certificate*. This is a stupid design mistake - there are many within their under specified API unfortunately.

Comment: Why does the windows core have to be so confusing? The top level part is an awesome OS. I have an idea...

Comment: @Assam ok it's harder but the only solution that I can think of now appears to be; write a custom C++ extension. https://docs.python.org/3/extending/extending.html

Comment: hmm..write a custom c++ extension may take some time :P.
Thanks Legorooj and Maarten

Comment: @Assam better method; `CryptoAPI` is a `dll` file. So you can call that with `ctypes`. Example https://stackoverflow.com/questions/252417/how-can-i-use-a-dll-file-from-python https://docs.python.org/3/library/ctypes.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can interface with the `Crypt32` `dll` Using ctypes to access it's functions.

[How can I use a DLL file from Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/252417/how-can-i-use-a-dll-file-from-python) provides a good idea, but is written in python 2.5, so see the tutorial in [the docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ctypes.html) for info and a reference.

Comment: I wrote a custom c++ extension and it worked. I also tried ctypes, it's too cumbersome...

Comment: `ctypes` can be frustrating can't it!