# Possible run some functions in dll files on UNIX, (Delphi)

Tags: python, unix, dll

I have some dll file create's on Delphi, i need's by some calls functions in python3 using  **ctypes** module **cdll**. I recieving an exception in call some func like: **invalid ELF header**.
How i may using dll's in python on linux?

Comment: you can import **ctypes**, to work with dll. You can put minimum reproducible code here?

Comment: This might help you - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/252417/how-can-i-use-a-dll-file-from-python