# How to call the C code in Python to make an interaction b/w two languages?

Tags: python, c

I am working on a project in which I am trying to make the interaction C code and Python. It means that I want to **call the C code in Python**.  I googled it but the solutions were not understandable for me.

What are the ways to do this?

Comment: Most likely, you want to compile the C code as a shared library and use it from Python via ctypes. There's plenty of examples.

Comment: There is extensive documentation on extending and embedding, in the Python documentation. Start here https://docs.python.org/3/ and look for the heading **Extending and Embedding**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have to compile your c code as a shared library and you'll be able to call functions using python's `ctypes` API. here is a simple example on how to do it.

#### lib.c

```c
__declspec(dllexport) int add(int a, int b);

int add(int a, int b) {
    return a + b;
}
```

#### compile (using msvc here)

```
cl /LD lib.c
```

#### app.py

```py
from ctypes import *
lib = cdll.LoadLibrary('lib.dll')
print(lib.add(1, 2))  ## this will print 3
```

for more see :
https://docs.python.org/3/library/ctypes.html 
[How can I use a DLL file from Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/252417/how-can-i-use-a-dll-file-from-python)
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=p_LUzwylf-Y&t=277s