# How to perform UDS session unlock using security dll from python program?

Tags: python, can-bus, unlock, uds

I want to automate some WDBI services  which requires security unlock.
I have a dll which can be invoked from CANoe, but I don't want to use canoe hardware also I don't know the function calls in the dll.
Is there any way that I can invoke dll from python program to perform session unlock?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I use a DLL file from Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/252417/how-can-i-use-a-dll-file-from-python)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With the DLL at hand you could use a tool like [DependencyWalker](https://www.dependencywalker.com/) to see the exported symbols of the DLL. But if you already know that your DLL works in CANoe, it will follow the APIs specified [by Vector Informatik](https://assets.vector.com/cms/content/know-how/_application-notes/AN-IDG-1-017_SecurityAccess.pdf) to be implemented in an Security Access DLL for CANoe: GenerateKeyEx & GenerateKeyExOpt.

GenerateKeyEx:

```
int VKeyGenResult ExGenerateKeyEx (
  const unsigned char* ipSeedArray,
  unsigned int iSeedArraySize,
  const unsigned int iSecurityLevel,
  const char* ipVariant,
  unsigned char* iopKeyArray,
  unsigned int iMaxKeyArraySize,
  unsigned int& oActualKeyArraySize );
```

GenerateKeyExOpt:

```
VKeyGenResult ExOptGenerateKeyExOpt (
  const unsigned char* ipSeedArray,
  unsigned int iSeedArraySize,
  const unsigned int iSecurityLevel,
  const char* ipVariant,
  const char* ipOptions,
  unsigned char* iopKeyArray,
  unsigned int iMaxKeyArraySize,
  unsigned int& oActualKeyArraySize );
```

Then it is just a matter of calling to this Dll from python, i.e. using [ctypes](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ctypes.html).

```
import ctypes

mylib = ctypes.WinDLL("./GenerateKeyExImpl.dll")
seed = (ctypes.c_byte * 4)(0xff, 0xfe, 0xfd, 0xfc) # these bytes you should get from the ECU i.e.
# Tx 27 01
# Rx 67 01 ff fe fd fc
key = (ctypes.c_byte * 4)() # this will contain the secret key after Dll call
keylength = ctypes.c_int(4) # this will contain the secret key length after Dll call
mylib.ExGenerateKeyEx(
     ctypes.pointer(seed), # Seed from the ECU
     ctypes.c_int(4), # Example: Seed length = 4 bytes
     ctypes.c_int(1), # Example: Security Level 1
     POINTER(c_int)(), # Example: NULL = No variant string
     ctypes.pointer(key), # Key to send back to the ECU
     ctypes.c_int(4), # Example: Key Max length = 4 bytes
     ctypes.pointer(keylength), # Example: Seed length = 4 bytes
)
# TODO: Send "key" back to the ECU i.e.
# Tx 27 02 XX XX XX XX
# Rx 67 02
```