# List all methods in a DLL along with the type of argument it accepts and value returned

Tags: python, python-3.x, clr, ctypes, python.net

Can any one please let me know how to load a DLL in Python and list all methods in it along with the type of argument it accepts and its return value type?

Comment: You want to read a ```.dll``` file? If so: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/252417/how-can-i-use-a-dll-file-from-python

Comment: But I need to find the signature of the function - I mean what the function accepts as an argument and it return type

Comment: C APIs only make the function name available from the DLL.  You need the DLL header file.  A tool such as [DUMPBIN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/dumpbin-reference?view=msvc-160) can display the function names, e.g. `dumpbin /exports <dll>`

Comment: Thanks - but dumpbin /exports <dll> still reports the function names not its complete signature?

Comment: That's what I said, the only information with just the DLL is function names for C APIs.  You **need** a header file for C APIs.  You mentioned Python.net, so perhaps you have a C# DLL, and there are mechanisms (reflection) to read that.  Be more specific if that's what you want.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification - unfortunately the DLL is made out of C/C++ language and then I presume there is no other way to find out the functions full signature as I do not have the header files

Comment: For C, a function like `double function2(int a, char* b, double c) { return 1.0; }` would only export `function2` from the DLL.  For C++, a name-mangled form is exported that indicates parameters, but it looks like `?function2@@YANHPEADN@Z` (MS compiler).  On online tool like https://demangler.com/ can decode it to get the types of the parameters and return value, but not the parameter names, so no indication of what to pass.  Also `ctypes` doesn't work with C++.