# How do I call a. DLL file using Python？

Tags: python, c, dll

The Python project I'm writing now requires a.dll file，After googling, I found that pythonnet is a package that references.dll files，But when I actually use it, I have a problem。Here is my code.and code file structure as shown in the picture[image: []
][2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5uYkx.png)1.The error is shown in Figure 2[image]

```
import clr
clr.AddReference("My")
from My import *
```

Thank you in advance。
ps:python version:3.8.6

Comment: here is picture2

Comment: Refer : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/252417/how-can-i-use-a-dll-file-from-python